# Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject error behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

I have some questions about `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject()`:

1) Can it fail (provided that I give an instantiated managed object as parameter)?

2) If the answer to 1) is yes, can it throw an exception?

3) If the answer to 1) is yes, what is its return value in case of failure?

I am apologizing if those questions are dumb, but the [respective documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getiunknownforobject(v=vs.110).aspx) says exactly nothing about any of the questions, and reading [the source code of the Marshal class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs) did not help either (`GetIUnknownforObject()` just calls `GetIUnknownForObjectNative()`, and there is no source code for the latter; its attributes only show that it is implemented internally somehow).

The questions although apply to Marshal.Release, but let's consider this a bonus ...

Comment: You *must* assume it won't fail, using try/catch-em-all will catch and ignore something nasty.  Source code is on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you very much and +1, I'll then assume they won't fail. Regarding your hint about GitHub: The source code of Marshal.cs at GitHub seems to be the same as that at referencesource.microsoft.com. Additionally, I have searched the whole repository at GitHub for GetIUnknownForObjectNative(), but did not get additional information. Did I miss something?

Comment: CoreCLR project, not CoreFx project.  src/vm/marshalnative.cpp

Comment: Now *that* is what I am calling an answer. I doubt that I can work my way through all these macros in a short time, though. But when taking a first look, I at least have learned that it could throw exceptions (and I will catch these), and at least I have learned that the return value will be NULL if it fails without throwing an exception.